# Return all data back in new node in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

This is my inputted data:

[image]

This is my function:

```
exports.updateAll = functions.database.ref('/update/{uid}/{values}').onCreate(event => {
    const data = event.data.val()   
    console.log(data)
    return db.ref(`somewhereElse/somepath/`).update(data)
})
```

This is the error I am recieving:

[image]

Is it possible to update all the created values back into another path? I thought creating a const with the event.data.val() would work, but then I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your reference for the `onCreate` trigger is `/update/{uid}/{values}` and so the event data will be that of the `values`. For example, the event data for `/update/{uid}/email` would be a string, and this is not an object containing children.

If you have a reason for needing to trigger this way, there is a solution to the error you are getting.

```
functions.database.ref('/update/{uid}/{values}').onCreate(event => {

    const key = event.params.values
    const value = event.data.val()

    console.log(key, value)

    return db.ref(`somewhereElse/somepath/{key}`).set(value)
})
```

The key value that was created can be retrieved from the event params and data. Then we can interpolate the key into the somewhere else ref, and set the value instead of updating it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the problem is the last line when setting the value to another path. That is where the error appears.

Comment: Yes I understand you problem. You are trying to update rather than set. Update requires an object with children, but your trigger event data is a string.